# Find but a SQL Server database version

Tags: sql-server, ssis, restore, database-restore

I have a little big problem. I was backed up with a database and had to work on it to create SSIS views and jobs. I've been working on it for 3 months now and I've just done a manipulation inadvertently.

I restored the database in its original version as when I received it. So I lost my SSIS Views and Jobs.

I must find them quickly. Is there a way to do a "go back" or how I can find my base in its state before my mishandling.

If a point is not clear I am at voting disposal. I have read some post but he does not speak specifically about my case.

- Windows 8.1
- SQL Server 2012

Comment: Don't you have weekly and/or daily backups you can restore from?

Comment: If you restored over the top of your database and you don't have a backup of it there is nothing, and I mean nothing, you can do.

Comment: i have not done a weekly or daily backups i have done myself. i'm new on it. is the system itself done it?

Comment: can not i with the log history restore a previous version?

Answer (score 0):

i have found a way base on server log (i think) on this link.
https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/reverting-your-sql-server-database-back-to-a-specific-point-in-time/

***Using SQL Server Management Studio***

Thanks for your help, it gives me where to search